# Why ProgressBar of bootstrap not appearing?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, progress-bar, react-bootstrap

I am using ProgressBar of react-bootstrap but its not working as expected:

```
<ProgressBar now={percentageSales} />
```

where `percentageSales` is a dynamic value different for different components.

The progressBar is not appearing in my case.

Comment: How does percentage sales exactly looks like?

Answer (score 0):

try to add into the app component the following

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```